# Changing the connection timezone in MySQL

Tags: mysql, timezone

My server is running in  `MDT`

So I used following one to convert `EST`

```
SET  time_zone = '-5:00'
```

But, how can I switch it to `EDT` because

```
While `EST` is only valid in winter, while in summer how to change it to `EDT`
```

I just try to used named time zone. But I am getting following error

```
 #1298 - Unknown or incorrect time zone: 'America/Toronto'
```

I don't understand how to solve this problem

How can i switch

> UTC -05 TO UTC-04

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since you're using Windows, your going to have to import the time zone description tables to your MySQL server.

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/timezones.html

Comment: This is not limited to Windows, on Ubuntu I also had to load the timezone table as described in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510052/changing-the-connection-timezone-in-mysql/16946123#16946123

Comment: My env (OS X, Mysql 5.6.13) gave me an obscure error "ERROR 1406 (22001) at line 38916: Data too long for column 'Abbreviation' at row 1". I hacked around it by running `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | sed 's/Local time zone must be set--see zic manual page/(ERROR)/' | mysql -uroot mysql` (See also http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68861)

Answer (score 73):

For Linux, BSD, and Mac OS X if you need to load the timezone table do this:

```
$ mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -uroot mysql
```

Comment: This was also what I did to fix the issue. The following page describes this process: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html

Comment: I think you should add  `-p` option after `-uroot` in order to use root password

Comment: it's giving me the warning 
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it

Answer (score 5):

For me on **Windows** using **WampServer**:

- download the POSIX version from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/timezones.html
- unzip it
- put all files in wamp mysql data: C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.11\data\mysql
- restart wamp

More Info:

“To use a time zone package that contains .frm, .MYD, and .MYI files for the MyISAM time zone tables, download and unpack it. These table files are part of the mysql database, so you should place the files in the mysqlsubdirectory of your MySQL server's data directory. Stop the server before doing this and restart it afterward”

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html#time-zone-installation

Answer (score 3):

In case of **Mysql8** and want to set **EDT** timezone **'America/New_York'** then follow the below steps:

1. Go to the /etc/my.cnf
2. Add this under [mysqld]
   default-time-zone='America/New_York'
3. systemctl restart mysqld

If you face the issue realted fatal error like this:

```
Fatal error: Illegal or unknown default time zone
```

Then do the following steps:

1. first remove the entry from /etc/my.cnf file for **default-time-zone='America/New_York'**
2. Go to shell(exit from mysql) and run the command

   ```
   $ mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root -p mysql
   ```
3. Add the line again
4. Restart mysql

Comment: This worked for me. On Ubuntu, my.cnf is located `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, restart with `sudo service mysql restart`, confirm with `SELECT @@global.time_zone;`

Comment: The question is about changing it for the connection, not the server.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a zoneinfo name such as "America/New_York" instead of the abbreviation (which is only valid for half the time)?

Ideally, you shouldn't use the server time zone at all of course - store dates in UTC and then convert it to the appropriate time zone in the client code. (This does depend on what you're storing, mind you. Future date/time values specified by a user with a time zone should be stored that way, not converted to *any* other time zone, in case the rules change between now and the future date/time. But for instants in time recorded by machines, e.g. for logging, transactions etc, I'd definitely store UTC. I would never suggest storing "just the local time and assume that the server and the client have the same rules".)

Comment: i try that **SET  time_zone = 'America/New_York'** but it doen't work,i generates error #1298 - Unknown or incorrect time zone: 'America/New_York'

Comment: @gowri: Without knowing anything about how you're inserting data into the database (e.g. which language/platform) it's hard to know what to suggest in terms of storing in UTC. As for valid time zones - I believe that's operating-system dependent; which operating system are you using?

Comment: i'm using php and oc is windows xp,server wamp

Comment: @gowri: You *may* find it works if you can find out the Windows time zone ID for New York. I don't know it offhand. As for UTC... are you trying to insert the current time? If so, use UTCTIMESTAMP(). Alternatively, just setting the time zone to "UTC" might do what you need...

Comment: Ideally? So, either you convert it in MySQL or you convert it in code... makes no difference

Comment: @MartinZvarík: I wouldn't say it "makes no difference". There are various differences: 1) you may not have the same degree of control over the database and over the code. For example, it may be easier to update the time zone data your code uses than the data your server uses. 2) Using the server's default time zone leaves your system brittle to environment changes. 3) It may well make a difference to the queries you can easily support, and how efficient they are. (You don't want queries to have to perform time zone conversions.) There are plenty of subtleties involved in this sort of decision.

Comment: @JonSkeet In most website cases you store times where the company is located and then make conversions if needed, because your PHP has timezone setting, and MySQL has timezone setting... So, what you suggested is to store times in UTC and then make conversions, which is imo bad advice, an unnecessary overhead in most cases and has zero benefits (you still convert times, but from UTC+0)

Comment: @MartinZvarík: I would take *great* issue with storing everything as a local time. There are all kinds of reasons why that's a bad idea, and it *particularly* falls down with "where the company is located" when companies can very easily move, grow etc. UTC is certainly not *always* the right answer, but I'd definitely prefer that to "always store in the local time zone of the company" and hoping that won't change, and that you can always set system defaults. You claim there are "zero benefits" to storing in UTC, but I'd argue that being environment-independent is a *huge* benefit.

Comment: @MartinZvarík: Then there are issues of being able to handle time zone rule changes in a controlled manner, in just one place (rather than a mixture of client and database), dealing with times that could be ambiguous or skipped in the local time zone, and far more. (For example, if you're storing transactions in the local time zone, you won't have an easy total ordering - 1:45 can occur before 1:15 if they're at different sides of a daylight saving transition.) Time zones can be complicated - the idea that you can just ignore them by storing everything as local time is just incorrect IMO.

Comment: I think we got lost... if I insert anything in MySQL it will use the timezone setting... so, sorting transactions when one transaction is from USA and other from CHINA is not complicated

Comment: @MartinZvarík: No, it really is, if you're storing the local time. Suppose you're in London and record these two transaction local times: "2019-10-27T01:45:00" and "2019-10-27T01:15:00". How would you order those times? You can't, unambiguously - because the hour between 1am and 2am occurs twice in London on October 27th 2019, due to a DST transition. You also can't unambiguously convert that to another time zone, for exactly the same reason. This is just *one* aspect of time zones that's complicated. There are many more, most of which I've learned about while authoring NodaTime...

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completeness, Mac users can find `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql` utility in `/usr/local/mysql/bin` directory.

Hence the complete command will be `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | ./mysql -p -u root mysql`

I spent hours to find the utility, the above path may save yours!