# mySQL TIME function and Timezone

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, time

I want to use the `NOW()` function with a specific timezone, say GMT+8 for a user and GMT-2 for another user. How can I achieve this?

I am guessing that the time for `NOW()` is related somewhat to the timezone and time of the SQL server, but I want it to be such that FN(GMT+8) always give me the `NOW()` in GMT+8 irregardless of the timezone the SQL server is in.

Mini question: How do i display/know the current time of the SQL server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) function provides the current time in the local timezone of the server.  If you wish to convert to a different timezone, you can use [`CONVERT_TZ()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz)

---

**UPDATE**:

You can use a per-connection timezone (that doesn't affect the system timezone) and get the effect you want:

```
mysql> select now();
+---------------------+
| now()               |
+---------------------+
| 2011-06-03 22:40:51 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET time_zone = '+08:00';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select now();
+---------------------+
| now()               |
+---------------------+
| 2011-06-04 10:41:15 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Good call...usually I do that but I'm distracted by this shiny new MacBook Pro tonight :p  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks!! With CONVERT_TZ(), do I need to know the timezone of the server for the 2nd argument for CONVERT_TZ(), or is there a way to set this 2nd argument as the time zone of the server?

Comment: So if you wanted to use `CONVERT_TZ()` to convert FROM server time (+08:00) TO some other time (e.g. US Eastern) the usage would be:  `SELECT CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),@@session.time_zone,'-04:00')`

Comment: @aj : i am having doubt, if my web server working in MDT, SET TIMEZONE ='-4:00' will minus 4 hours from MDT OR GMT to convert EDT please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510052/changing-the-connection-timezone-in-mysql